# How do I use awk to modify a yml file?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to use `awk` to modify a yml file. The logic I want is that if the key `specialKey` already exists WITH a subkey `subkey` then do nothing, otherwise I want to insert the subkey (and its associated value) under the specialkey. Eg if my file `mine.yml` looks like

```
blah:
   moreStuff:
      ...
specialKey:
   A:
      ...
   B:
      ...
   subKey:
      ...
   C:
      ...
...
```

then do nothing since `specialKey` already exists WITH `subkey` as a subkey. But if it's missing, then I wish to insert `specialKey: ...`. I'm having trouble understanding how to use awk and this was my first attempt:

`awk '1;/specialKey:/{foundSpecialKey=1;}; foundSpecialKey && /subKey:/{foundSubKey=1}; foundSpecialKey && foundSubkey!=1 && //{foundLifecycle=0; foundResults=0;  print "my content";}' mine.yml`

but this still inserts in the content even if the `specialKey: ... subKey: ...` already exists. How can I proceed?

Comment: Don't. Use a tool that understands yaml, like one of the several (unrelated and incompatible with each other, alas) yq programs.

Comment: Agree about find a yaml tool, but your initial condition `1;` evaluates as true for each line read, so each line will be printed, (possibly duplicated). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]/ && NR==FNR 
                              { 
                                key=$0 
                              } 
key=="specialKey:" && NR==FNR 
                              { 
                                if (match($0,/subKey:/)) 
                                                        { 
                                                          mtch=1 
                                                        } 
                              } 
 NR!=FNR && mtch!=1 && /^specialKey:/ 
                              { 
                                print $0;
                                print "   subKey:";
                                print "      ..." 
                              } 
 NR!=FNR && mtch==1 
                              { 
                                 print $0 
                              } 
 NR!=FNR && mtch!=1 && !/^specialKey:/ 
                              { 
                                 print $0 
                              }' mine.yml mine.yml
```

Process the yaml file twice. In the first pass (NR==FNR) we establish whether the subKey exists. Then in the second pass (NR!=FNR) we print the subkey under the line beginning with "specialKey:" if we haven't found a match for subkey in the previous pass (mtch!=1). In all other instances, we just print the line